# [DocumentDB .NET SDK]What is the difference between ReadDocumentAsync and CreateDocumentQuery when replacing

Tags: .net, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Please look at the code first.

In step 8, the field is not updated.
In step 11&12, the field is updated.

I have 2 questions.

What is the difference between ReadDocumentAsync and CreateDocumentQuery when replacing?

Is it appropriate to use the value obtained by DocumentQuery for replacement?

---

ConsoleApp

NuGet Package(Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB 1.19.1,Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.1)

---

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static string endpoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["endpoint"];
    static string key = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"];
    static string database = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["database"];
    static string collection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["collection"];
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConnectionPolicy cp = new ConnectionPolicy()
        {
            ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
            ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Https,
            RetryOptions = new RetryOptions()
            {
                MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests = 5,
                MaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds = 60,
            }
        };

        var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpoint), key, cp);
        //Step1 Create Database
        client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(new Database { Id = database }).Wait();

        //Step2 Create Collection(400RU)
        client.CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExistsAsync(UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(database),
            new DocumentCollection
            {
                Id = collection,
                PartitionKey = new PartitionKeyDefinition()
                { Paths = new Collection<string>() { "/partitionKey" } }
            }
            , new RequestOptions { OfferThroughput = 400 }).Wait();

        //Step3 Insert TestData
        var id1 = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        client.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(database, collection)
            , new TestDocument() { TestField = "initialvalue", PartitionKey = "default", Id = id1, }).Wait();
        var id2 = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        client.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(database, collection)
            , new TestDocument() { TestField = "initialvalue", PartitionKey = "default", Id = id2, }).Wait();

        //Step4 ID1 GetDocument(ReadDocument)
        var readDocument = client.ReadDocumentAsync<TestDocument>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(database, collection, id1),
            new RequestOptions() { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("default") }).Result.Document;

        //Step5 ID2 GetDocument(DocumentQuery)
        var queryDocument = client.CreateDocumentQuery<TestDocument>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(database, collection),
            new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 1, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = false, })
            .Where(x => x.PartitionKey == "default" && x.Id == id2)
            .AsDocumentQuery().ExecuteNextAsync<TestDocument>().Result.FirstOrDefault();

        //Step6 ChangeValue
        readDocument.TestField = "newvalue";
        queryDocument.TestField = "newvalue";

        //Step7 ID1 Replace
        var updateResult1 = client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(database, collection, readDocument.Id), readDocument).Result;
        //Step8 ID2 Replace
        var updateResult2 = client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(database, collection, queryDocument.Id), queryDocument).Result;

        //Step9 ID1 select
        var id1Updated = client.ReadDocumentAsync<TestDocument>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(database, collection, id1),
            new RequestOptions() { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("default") }).Result.Document;
        //Step10 ID2 select
        var id2Updated = client.ReadDocumentAsync<TestDocument>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(database, collection, id2),
            new RequestOptions() { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("default") }).Result.Document;

        Console.WriteLine(id1Updated.TestField); //newvalue
        Console.WriteLine(id2Updated.TestField); //initialvalue
        Console.ReadLine();

        //Step11 ID2 SetPropertyValue
        queryDocument.SetPropertyValue("testField", "newvalue2");
        //Step12 ID2 Replace
        var updateResultX = client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(database, collection, queryDocument.Id), queryDocument).Result;
        //Step13 ID2 select
        var id2UpdatedX = client.ReadDocumentAsync<TestDocument>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(database, collection, id2),
            new RequestOptions() { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("default") }).Result.Document;
        Console.WriteLine(id2UpdatedX.TestField); //newvalue2
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
public class TestDocument : Document
{
    [JsonProperty("partitionKey")]
    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("testField")]
    public string TestField { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi,any updates now? Does my answer helps you?

Comment: I got the expected behavior after adding [queryDocument = (dynamic) queryDocument;] before [queryDocument.TestField = "newvalue";].
Why does this work?

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/117

Comment: Hi, sak_o. I'll check the thread you offered and post my thoughts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the difference between ReadDocumentAsync and
>   CreateDocumentQuery when replacing?

You should use `ReadDocumentAsync` over a query for simple ID lookups.

On the server side, a `ReadDocumentAsync` (GET on REST API) is more lightweight in terms of throughput (RUs) and latency. There's no SQL parsing/compilation/index scans, it's just a direct lookup.

`ReadDocumentAsync` will throw that DocumentClientException when it can't find the specific document (returning a 404 in the status code) which is mentioned  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.readdocumentasync?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=azure-dotnet#overloads).

To get around dealing with this exception, you could make a query instead of a direct read, by using `CreateDocumentQuery()` first.Then, you'll simply get a result set.

> Is it appropriate to use the value obtained by DocumentQuery for
>   replacement?

Yes, you could use the docuemnt obtained by DocumentQuery to do replace operations. Please refer to the snippet of code as below:

```
private async Task updateDoc()
{
    string EndpointUri = "xxxxx";
    string PrimaryKey = "xxxxx";
    DocumentClient client;

    client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUri), PrimaryKey);

    Document doc = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("db", "coll"))
                .Where(r => r.Id == "**")
                .AsEnumerable()
                .SingleOrDefault();

    MyMode mode= (dynamic)doc;

    mode.name = "updated value";

    //replace document
    Document updateddoc = await client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(doc.SelfLink, mode);


    Console.WriteLine(updateddoc);
}

public class MyMode
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Hope it helps you.